# How to interface R's classes (S4 or S3) with C's classes

Tags: c, r

I need to call a C function from R passing some object in the form of classes (S3 or S4). In C I will handle structures (dynamically allocate memory for arguments, set values, etc.) and then I need to return the modified structures to R(maybe by references). I think it should be possible to create a similar class in R and then pass it to C.

Given the possibility to write C extension for R, I checked `.C` and `.Call` function in R to call C functions, but I can't found out how to pass classes to these functions. They only seem to accept common type defined as SEXP and derivation that does not include personalized classes.

If someone faced this problem I would be grateful for his help

Comment: You may want to start by reading through Hadley Wickham's [chapter on R's C interface](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html), which should give you a solid background on writing C code to be called from R. It does not cover your exact question precisely, but honestly, I feel you would be better served by consulting this information before attempting to implement any solution someone might be able to provide you here. (Also, your problem statement is not very specific, so you may not get great responses yet anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I've already read what you suggest and even the official manuals on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#System-and-foreign-language-interfaces), but as you said they don't answer my question.

Comment: Note that S3 classes, under the hood, **are** "common types"; most often, they are a `list` in R, which is a `VECSXP` in C. They just have a class attribute, and sometimes other attributes. You can get and set attributes for an R object on the C side via [`getAttrib` and `setAttrib`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Attributes). Converting a struct to an R object should be straightforward in a custom application; you just create the appropriate R object, and assign the data as appropriate. I'm not really sure what further info you need

Comment: OK, thanks, your comment has been very useful and it seems that also R's refClasses can be passed to C as they were "common types" so that I can modify them in C and have them modified also in R without being returned.